# Send TCP traffic to the ingress's namespace with Nginx Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm using an Nginx Ingress controller to open connections to a postgres database with the `--tcp-services-configmap=k8s-ingress/k8s-ingress-tcp` flag. That configmap looks like

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  "5432": namespace-a/the-postgres-svc:5432
kind: ConfigMap
```

This portion works perfectly, however I would like to open up another service on the same port, `5432` to `namespace-b/the-postgres-svc:5432`.

Is there any way to have the namespace selected be based on the namespace from the ingress resource? Since the data key would be identical if I were to just add that record to the after the "namespace-a" record I am not able to just append to the configmap data.

Thanks!

Comment: Say I use the `psql` command-line client to connect to port 5432 on the ingress service.  How does it know which back-end to route me to?

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to have services on the same port in different namespaces.
I have found interesting [step-by-step tutorial](https://github.com/ProProgrammer/cross-namespace-nginx-ingress-kubernetes) for this approach.

Firstly you should create two namespaces:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: namespace-a
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: namespace-b
```

Than have your services and deployment definition, where the difference is between `name` and `namespace` fields:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: namespacea-nginx
  namespace: namespace-a
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    run: nginx
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: namespaceb-nginx
  namespace: namespace-b
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    run: nginx
```

Deployment files:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
  namespace: namespace-a
spec:
  ...
```

---

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
  namespace: namespace-b
spec:
  ...
```

And finally, Ingress files definitions:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: namespace-a
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: namespacea.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: namespacea-nginx
          servicePort: 5432
        path: /
```

---

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: namespace-b
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: namespaceb.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: namespaceb-nginx
          servicePort: 5432
        path: /
```